# How to get all images from img tag and background images from HTML page using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to get all images from HTML page.
want to get all images from `<img>` tag source  or get images from element background from HTML contents.

How can I get?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just loop over all elements on the page and check if it's an image or it has some image background. The biggest problem of this solution is that it's very slow (however its performance could be improved in several ways). Here is the code:

```
$('*').each(function(){ 
    var backImg;

    if ($(this).is('img')) {
        console.log($(this).attr('src'));
    } else {
        backImg = $(this).css('background-image');
        if (backImg != 'none') console.log(backImg.substring(4, backImg.length-1));
    }
});
```

Comment: This solution is correct, however it does not deal with developers who may have set the background property to a url, instead of the background-image. Though that case may or may not be important to the original poster, it is perhaps a case to consider. Further, performance is an issue with this solution, unless it is absolutely necessary, to do perform this operation, the OP should consider a different approach.

Answer (score 9):

for getting images from all the image tags i think you could simply iterate over a image tag

```
$('img').each(function(){
alert($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

for getting all of the background images you will have to look for the background property in all the elements.

```
$('*').each(function(){
alert($(this).css('background-image'));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

For gettings images from img tag, use this

```
var images = [];
$("img").each(function(){
    if(this.src){images.push(this.src);}
});
$('*').each(function(){
    var bg = $(this).css('background-image');
    if( bg && bg != 'none'){images.push(bg);}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Select all  tags on the page with `$('img')`
To find all the background images from HTML content, you would want to go through each element, check if it has the background-image CSS property, and if so, record the value of that property.
I think it would look something like this:

```
$('*').each(function() {
   if ($(this).css('background-image') != '')
   //record however you're recording it
});
```