# Hide previously viewed images using a Greasemonkey script

Tags: greasemonkey

I'm trying to write a Greasemonkey script that will hide images in [Google Image Search](http://images.google.com/) that I've already seen (so that I won't be shown the same image in search results twice, when making multiple searches.) Is there any way to obtain a list of images from search results using a Greasemonkey script so that I can prevent the images from loading after they are viewed? In order to do this, I'll need to find a way to prevent images from loading after they've previously been viewed.

```
var blockedImageList = new Array();

function blockImages(imageList){
    //prevent images from loading if they are on the blocked image list,
                                      //which is an array of image URLs
}

function getAllImagesFromPage(){
    //add all of the images on the current page to the blocked image list.
}
```

Comment: I'll need to find a way to stop images from loading after they've previously been loaded on a specific page. The two questions above should address both of those issues.

Comment: This question explains how to obtain the list of all images on a page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641596/how-to-get-all-images-from-img-tag-and-background-images-from-html-page-using-jq

Comment: Also, this question explains how to remove a list of images using a Greasemonkey script.